# Control positions in Runtime not consistent with designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let me explain put it in just a few simplest lines.

- I made a new C#/WPF application project in VS 2013 ultimate (x64).
- On MainWindow I insert (for example) a button at bottom-right, actually anywhere..
- See image below, but the position of the buttons at runtime does not match what it looks like when I am designing

[image]

As you can see from the marked up spots in the 2 images, the controls are mispositioned.

I tried to change some XAML attributes, setting min/max sizes, and so on and on.  I am running a fresh-install Windows 7 Ultimate (x64) OS, with "Windows 7" aero theme.

I played around MainWindow/Grid properties (tried almost every one), also when I loaded up some custom theme (for example: Expression Dark) issue persists.

Comment: Is it anchored to the top left or bottom right

Comment: Are you laying these out on a Canvas, or on a Grid with a single cell? You might want to read up on containers is XAML layout containers. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh969155.aspx for example, it's for Windows 8 really but largely applies to WPF as well.

Comment: @ta.speot.is There is no Anchor property in WPF. It is a new project, all defaults, I only changed property value for sliders..It is grid.

Comment: @OmegaExtern I am sorry for removing most everything from your post, but you had a lot of extraneous information that wasn't relevant or was too chatty and was probably going to get downvoted and/or closed.  I tried to trim it down to focus on the specific problem.  If you don't feel I captured your problem correctly, feel free to edit it again, but try to stick with specific details.  You may find [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the help center a good resource for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't get excited so much. Have some control on your temper.

It seems that you have not set the `Right Margin` of the button you have circled `Red` in the above image. Try to set the appropriate margins from the `Property Window` of the corresponding button and see what happens!

Comment: Ahhh, thanks a bunch @Wasif Hossain! Also I'd give +1 for ta.speot.is ;) I didn't know what are these stickies on window border used for.. Now I understand! Thanks to both of you!